# promissing "coming soon" features in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone

it's allowed to promise future features or content, such as levels, labeled as "comming soon" in my iphone app ?

Comment: Your question is vague and badly spelled. I can't decipher what you are asking. Could you rephrase the question to be more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is technically allowed but I would caution you about doing this.

If you promise something, you need make good on that promise as customers will hold you to it.

It's always good to follow the rule: "under-promise and over-deliver".

Hint that there's new features coming, but don't get into too many specifics.

In the app, I've used a link to my website that shows a "Sneak Peak" of what's coming, I've found it works well. That way, you can update the website at any time, adding and removing things as necessary before launch of the new features.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Pretty much what i needed to know. Thanks !